# Javascript md5 hash of different arrays yields same value

Tags: javascript, md5

Using the `md5` npm module, I'm trying to understand why running the following command with two different input values would yield the same hashed value.

```
const value1 = ["test1"];
const value2 = ["test2"];

const result1 = md5(value1);
const result2 = md5(value2);

// but

const result3 = md5(JSON.stringify(value1));
const result4 = md5(JSON.stringify(value2));

// result1 === result2
// result3 !== result4
```

Comment: [Issue #44](https://github.com/pvorb/node-md5/issues/44): _"If an Array of non-integers is mistakenly passed in, do not silently hash [0]"_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the source code:

> ```
>   md5 = function (message, options) {
>     // Convert to byte array
>     if (message.constructor == String)
>       if (options && options.encoding === 'binary')
>         message = bin.stringToBytes(message);
>       else
>         message = utf8.stringToBytes(message);
>     else if (isBuffer(message))
>       message = Array.prototype.slice.call(message, 0);
>     else if (!Array.isArray(message) && message.constructor !== Uint8Array)
>       message = message.toString();
>     // else, assume byte array already
> ```

If you pass it an array for the message (which you are in your first two cases) then it assumes you are passing it an array of bytes.

You are passing it an array of strings, so it breaks.

Comment: It's interesting to see code doing constructor comparisons, as that doesn't work in cross-realm situations (like a child window calling a function via `top`). (At least, that used to not work.)

Comment: @Pointy - It still doesn't, good point. Node.js code can get away with some things browser-based code can't (I can't immediately think of how you'd get a cross-realm object reference in Node.js), but...I would've flagged it in a code review. :-)